# Adding multiple conditions in required attribute and binding

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to create a JSF application. 
Sorry for this over ambitious requirement.
In the application the user will have three drop downs.

Can we add multiple required conditions into one required attribute?

If a user selects the country Mexico / value 3 from the first drop down then he is required to choose the option Cancun / value 6 from the multiselect

Also If he selects the drop down value Continent North America He is required to choose the option of  Chicago  / value 2 from the multiselect

I have added the binding , required attribute for multiSelectListbox for multiple required options but they are not triggered when the drop down is selected

```
<h:form>
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" skipDetailIfEqualsSummary="true" />

<p:panel header="Tranfer Destination" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
    <p:outputLabel for="country" value="Country: " />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{dropdownView.country}" style="width:150px" required="true" binding="#{country}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownView.countries}" />
        <p:ajax update="city"/
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputLabel for="Continent" value="Continent: " />
    <p:multiSelectListbox id="continent" value="#{dropdownView.continent}" style="width:150px" required="true" binding="#{continent}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Continent" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Asia" itemValue="1"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Europe" itemValue="2"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="South America"  itemValue="3"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="North America" itemValue="4"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Africa" itemValue="5"> </f:selectItem>
        <p:ajax update="city"/
    </p:multiSelectListbox>

    <p:outputLabel for="city" value="City: " />
    <p:multiSelectListbox id="city" value="#{dropdownView.city}" style="width:150px" required="#{(not empty param[country.6])  (not empty param[continent.4])}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select City" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="New York" itemValue="1"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Chicago" itemValue="2"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seattle"  itemValue="3"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Toronto" itemValue="4"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ontario" itemValue="5"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cancun" itemValue="6"> </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tijuana" itemValue="7"> </f:selectItem>
    </p:multiSelectListbox>
 </h:panelGrid>

<p:separator />

<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" action="#{dropdownView.displayLocation}" icon="pi pi-check" />
</p:panel>
</h:form>
```

List of Countries are populated from the database

```
ID NAME

1 USA-C
2 Canada-N
3 Mexico-C
```

The option Cancun / value 6 is required from the third drop down only If the user selects the country Mexico / value 3 from the first drop down.

The option  Chicago  / value 2 is required from the third drop down only If the user selects the continent North America / value 4 from the second drop down.

Other cities are optional for selection

Comment: What you use in the attribute is called EL... Expression Language. And your seems 'illogical' since it does not contain an and/or which any language logically would expect

Comment: This is rather basic  in that I cannot even find real matching duplicate in SO, but a search results in enough related hits https://duckduckgo.com/?q=el+and+or+jsf+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=fpas&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

If I have to do this, I won't use the `required` attribute and I will create a custom validator that checks the option selected on the first and second dropdown, and look if the third dropdown have the required values for the previous selection.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/custom.xhtml

Comment: I'd use the required attribute, since that IS a validator

Comment: @Kukeltje But maybe it is too much logic to add into an EL expression, that could be too complex to understand, and you have to update the components every time that any value change to make the others required or not, don't you think?

Comment: Same is needed with a custom validator... Otherwise these won't be shown either... And you CAN use one expresion in there with a field in a backing bean and put the logic in there, but that is still not a custom validator